# how to get two matches per line

Tags: perl

i need to get a word after `PgTrx` and a word after `Statusdescription`

log sample:

`status=1&newMainBalance=5486&serviceAmount=700&ExternalTrxId=asdf&PgTrxId=tfpsadf&amount=0&statusDescription=Failed&customerCode=1.1&newDedicatedBalance=0&secureHash=56a7sdyf&paidAmount=1000&responseMsg=%a1%a1%A1(PG_ID)&language=enHTTP/1.1"200186243**1/1210669**1"-""-""-""https://example.com.eg?statusDescription=Failed&externalTrxId=123&status=203&secureHash=asdf&pgTrxId=asdf`

i tried the below  but i only get 1 word after `statusdescription`:

```
perl -ne 'foreach my $p (split(/&/)) { if ($p =~ /statusDescription(=.*)/) { print "$1\n"; last } }'

cat file.txt | perl -ne 'forea ch my $p (split(/&/)) { if ($p =~ /statusDescription(=.*)/) { print "$1\n"; last } }'
```

i want to get the result as below.

```
PgTrxId=tfpsadf&statusDescription=Failed
```

but i got only

```
statusDescription=Failed
```

Comment: Your code contains a syntax error (`forea ch`). If you fix that, it doesn't produce the output you claim.

Comment: Do you want to match `PgTrxId` or `PgTrx`?

Answer (score 3):

Don't faff around with split. Parse the whole line into a hash, then select the keys you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @wanted = qw ( PgTrxId statusDescription );

while (<DATA>) {
   my %param = m/(\w+)=(\w+)/g;
   print Dumper \%param;

   print join ( "&", map { "$_:$param{$_}" } @wanted ),"\n";
}



__DATA__
status=1&newMainBalance=5486&serviceAmount=700&ExternalTrxId=asdf&PgTrxId=tfpsadf&amount=0&statusDescription=Failed&customerCode=1.1&newDedicatedBalance=0&secureHash=56a7sdyf&paidAmount=1000&responseMsg=%a1%a1%A1(PG_ID)&language=enHTTP/1.1"200186243**1/1210669**1"-""-""-""https://example.com.eg?statusDescription=Failed&externalTrxId=123&status=203&secureHash=asdf&pgTrxId=asdf
```

If you want that as a one liner:

```
perl -ne '%p = m/(\w+)=(\w+)/g; print join ( "&", map { "$_=$p{$_}" } ) qw ( PgTrxId statusDescription ),"\n"'
```

I've used `map` here for brevity, because that's useful in a one liner, but that's functionally equivalent to:

```
   my @list_of_wanted_things; 
   foreach my $word ( @wanted ) {
      push ( @list_of_wanted_things,  "$word=$param{$word}" ); 
   }
   print join "&", @list_of_wanted_things;
```

Comment: It works for the two parameters that we're specifically asked for here. But for some of the other parameters, you'd need to change the `(\w+)` that captures the value.

Answer (score 1):

Two obvious things that you'd want to change:

- Search for "PgTrxId" as well as "statusDescription"
- Remove the `last` so it doesn't stop after it's found one.

I've also used `(?: ... )` to cluster the search terms without capturing them.

```
perl -ne 'foreach my $p (split(/&/)) { if ($p =~ /(?:statusDescription|PgTrxId)(=.*)/) { print "$1\n" } }'
```

But I far prefer [Sobrique's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55570568/7231).

Answer (score 0):

if your data is in 'd' file,

```
perl -ne '@s = /\b(PgTrxId=[^&]+)|(&statusDescription=[^&]+)/xg;print @s' d
```

the result is in array variable @s